# website load time differs for more than 2 second on various try

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, load-time, front-end-optimization

I am working on to figure out the performance bottleneck of a website. I am using the chrome **empty cache and hard reload** option and hitting it using the incognito mode(with no extension enabled).

For determining the page load time, using the network tab of chrome tools and it reports huge variation when i hit same page using the same(empty cache and hard reload) option.

For ex:-

Below is the first hit, which shows load time is 8.2 sec with 25 requests and 477KB data :-

[image]

Just after when i again hit(2nd hit), i get the same no of request and size but load time increases to 9.25 sec.

[image]

And in 3rd hit , it reduces to just 6.89 second.

[image]

Now, my question is that i am doing the same thing, then why the **load time** varies a lot.

Comment: @user1274820 , let me know what information you need?

Comment: Are you on a wireless connection, or a wired connection?  Are you confident about the consistency of your internet connection?

Comment: i am on a high speed broadband company network.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some requests (styles, scripts, img) to 3rd party servers which have different time for download each time ( because 3rd party server may be more heavy loaded in that specific moment).

If thats the case and your code depends (on load event) on them - it is pretty possible that you received different page load times.